# Processing/Java play WAV in a playlist

Tags: java, arrays, processing, wav

I know I've posted a similar question before but I can't seem to sort it.

I have wrote a program which opens a WAV file, loops it forever and displays a visualizer, which is fine.

I can select many files with the following

```
chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
```

However it only plays the first WAV file and keeps looping that.

I am new to Java but am I right thinking that the selected WAV files need to be stored in an array and need to be called separately? As I would eventually want to load 25 WAV files around 30 seconds long each)

The code for choosing the files is below:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
chooser.setFileFilter(chooser.getAcceptAllFileFilter());
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
minim = new Minim(this);
player = minim.loadFile(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
player.loop();
fft = new FFT(player.bufferSize(), player.sampleRate());
```

Also, click order is not important at the moment as the files selected will be randomly played one after the other, forever.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `chooser.getSelectedFiles();`

```
File[] selectedFiles = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
```

then inside a for-loop play the files.

Now, if you want to loop over all songs, then you should have an upper while like below :

```
int loopTimes = 10;
while ( loopTimes > 0 )
{
   for ( File file : selectedFiles )
   {
      player = minim.loadFile( file.getAbsolutePath() );
      player.play();
   }

   loopTimes--;
}
```

I don't think the [API](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/audioplayer_class_audioplayer.html) for `Minim::AudioPlayer` supports `loop()` for multiple files.